# Sitecore connecting to MongoDB using SSL

Tags: mongodb

I'm using Sitecore 8.2 update 5 and just setup a MongoDB using SSL, and it works fine but when Sitecore tries to communicate with it, does not work at all.

In my ConnectionStrings.config, I've set as follows

**`mongodb://mongodb.mydomain.com/analytics?ssl=true`**

And Sitecore throws an error saying **Tracking.Current is not initialized**, however, if I remove SSL from MongoDB and the ?ssl=true parameter everything works fine.

Any idea how to properly establish the communication?

Comment: Have you tried looking at the following article: http://firebreaksice.com/configure-sitecores-mongo-client-use-ssl/

Comment: Yes, I did but it throws an error saying "Could not load file or assembly 'MongoDB.Driver, Version=1.10.0.62", and the MongoDB.Driver.dll is 2.4.4.0 originally. I tried to change it but didn't work either due other dependencies.

Comment: When do you see this error @ViniciusDeschamps? Would mind sharing the code customization you did to read the SSL settings?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't perform that, I got confused with the followin article https://getfishtank.ca/en/blog/connecting-to-mongodb-and-azure-documentdb-in-sitecore-over-ssl

Comment: It worked like a charm after I put some attention on the information you and @HishaamNamooya provided

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OOTB Sitecore does not communicate with Mongo using SSL, we need to implement a custom pipeline for such communication.

Customize the `Sitecore.Analytics.MongoDB.Config` by defining  a new Pipeline.

Now you have two approaches to establish SSL connection between Mongo and Sitecore.

1. SSL Integration using physical PFX file
2. SSL Integration reading Machine Key

Please have a look at [my blog post for more details](https://sitecorecompetencies.com/2017/03/15/sitecore-mongodb-with-ssl-customization/).